# Can we strictly reproduce Alexnet network architecture with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, imagenet

I want to strictly reproduce the [Alexnet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) neural network with Tensorflow 2:

[image]

From the [numerous implementations](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=alexnet%20github) that exist on the internet, I could not find any having the model split in two as described by the paper and the image above. I understand that it was done because of the GPU memory limitation at that time.

But I'm wondering if such implementation is possible with TensorFlow 2 and how?
How a model could be split in two, assigned to two different GPUs while still merging the output of some layers (layers 2, 5, 6).

I bet that Keras is too high level to handle this complexity, and the automated distributed strategy of TF makes it hard to control the device assignments and synchronization.

I gave a try by grouping the layers into models (e.g. layer 1 and 2) and assign those groups to their respective device using `tf.device('/GPU:x')`) while still concatenating the output. And then tried to parallelize and sync the layers across the two GPUs...

But I couldn't get any close.... So, any approach/suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is not very complicated if you use Functional API. Here I only demonstrate how to split it in two, or in many as you like

```py
inp = tf.keras.Input(input_shape=shape)
x1 = Layers.Conv2D(filters_1, kernel_size_1)(inp)
x2 = Layers.Conv2D(filters_2, kernel_size_2)(inp)
...
# Concatenate outputs of previous layers, be careful of dimension matching.
x = Layers.Concatenate()([x1, x2])
x = Layers.Dense(512)(x)
x = Layers.Dense(256)(x)
...
output = Layers.Dense(classes, activation="softmax")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = output)
```

Comment: How do you manage GPU assignment? The layer computing x1 needs to be on GPU 1 and layer computing x2 on GPU 2. And it’s the same for all split layers

Answer (score 0):

You can strictly reproduce AlexNet with only one GPU as if it was two if you follow the [repo](https://github.com/Eduardo-RP/Pretrained-AlexNet-TensorFlow-with-Weights). They have a h5 model that has the weights from ImageNet and you can just load it with Keras.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33570146)